# Allowed values for a property

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way in dart to only allow a number of values for a property?

```dart
class Kana {
  final String kana;
  final String romaji;
  final type = 'hiragana' | 'katakana';

  Kana({this.kana, this.romaji, this.type});
}
```

I'd like to make those values the only allowed values, preventing me to put a wrong value when initializing a Kana class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use enums.

```
void main() {
  var kana = Kana('x', 'y', Style.hiragana);
  print(kana);
}

class Kana {
  final String kana;
  final String romaji;
  final Style style;

  Kana(this.kana, this.romaji, this.style);
}

enum Style { hiragana, katakana }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `assert` to check the value of your type.

```
  Kana(this.kana, this.romaji, this.type)
      : assert(type == 'hiragana' || type == 'katakana');
```